Suddenly timed script gives error - .setTitle works but stops script
Suddenly a working script doesn't. There is an error on the first .setTitle, but it sets the title correctly anyway - however it then stops the script so the second .setTitle is not set.
questionMonTitle.setTitle(mondaydate);
  questionWedTitle.setTitle(weddaydate);



"Unexpected error while getting method or property setTitle on object Formapp.Item".

Any thoughts greatly appreciated
All sorts of script rewrites - but the issue is the same
I have listed the function below without lines that do not affect this issue:
function updateFormDEVELOPMENT(){
  var questionMon = 1879350946;
  var questionWed = 438313919;
  var form = FormApp.openById("1UeA5csiF76sJALNBjoaL0qq7c45OJP0vv8xVzgP1KwY"); // Auto weekly DEVELOPMENT signup form  THIS IS A PRACTICE Form -  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  //(This is a PRACTICE Response sheet)  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("FormResponses");
  var AutoWeeklySignup = ss.getSheetByName ("AutoWeeklySignup");
  var mondaydate = sheet.getRange("L1").getValue();  //Form question date, grabbed here from Sheet formula. Is also in Q4
  var weddaydate = sheet.getRange("M1").getValue();  //also in Q5
  var questionMonTitle = form.getItemById(questionMon);
  var questionWedTitle = form.getItemById(questionWed);
var formtitle = `${sheet.getRange("N1").getValue()}\n**${dayswarning}**`;   // triggers Friday 5PM, want warning on Friday turnover 
  sheet.getRange("H1").setValue('={"Mon Date"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", E1, ""))}');
  sheet.getRange("I1").setValue('={"Wed Date"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", F1, ""))}');
  sheet.getRange("J1").setValue('={"Mon y/n"; ArrayFormula( E2:E)}');
  sheet.getRange("K1").setValue('={"Wed y/n"; ArrayFormula( F2:F)}');
  sheet.getRange("L1").setValue('="Mon " & text(Today()+ (9-weekday(today() ))+7, "MMM d") &" -1:00 PM" ');
  sheet.getRange("M1").setValue('="Wed " & text(Today()+ (11-weekday(today() )) +7, "MMM d" ) & "- 6:30PM" ');
  sheet.getRange("N1").setValue('="Signup: Mon " & text( Today()+ (9-weekday(today() )) +7, "MMM d") & " & Wed " & text (Today() + (11-weekday(today() ))+7,"MMM d")');

  form.setTitle(formtitle); 
  questionMonTitle.setTitle(mondaydate);
  questionWedTitle.setTitle(weddaydate);
   }


Please add a [mcve]. In this case, as your script reads values from a spreadsheet, you should include the details of those values. Also, you should add the textual error message.

Note: form.setTitle(formtitle);   uses formtitle but this variable has not been declared.

Possibly related recent questions: Why does my form script error out after correctly setting Title? and .setHelpText throws an error: Unexpected error while getting the method or property setHelpText on object FormApp.Item.

Wicket: 1) I have edited back into my code snippet the 'var formtitile = ...' that is indeed in my full code.  Sorry I skipped that originally. 2) The error message text is in my original post "Unexpected error ..." .  3) For reproducible example, this is my "practice sheet" which is comparable to my real one: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hf5zmkW7_oFtt3OwJC1aMUiVRwX8DLPUIdnWFt-wr1Y/edit?usp=sharing   Many Many thanks for helping.

@silversmith Thanks for your reply. Please add the error message textually, precisely as is shown in the execution logs (the line number is missing). Regarding the "mcve", I don't think that the "setValue" methods are required to reproduce the problem, please remove them, and test your script again.

getItemById returns an Interface Item instance. This kind of object can't be modified directly. Use asTextItem() to get a Class TextItem object, then use setTitle(title).
function myFunction(){
 const questionMon = 1879350946;
 const form = FormApp.openById(/** Put here your form id */);
 const questionMonTitle = form.getItemById(questionMon).asTextItem(); 
 questionMonTitle.setTitle("New title");
}

Note: asTextItem() works for most question types. You should use another method for specific question types. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item to learn the complete list of methods of Interface Item.

I modified my original code as shown below. But this gave me: "Exception: Invalid conversion for item type : CHECKBOX" . I think we are close, but I'm still missing something here. Many Many thanks. I apologize for my confusion on using two sites.   Peter     ---
  const questionMonTitle = form.getItemById(questionMon).asTextItem();


@silversmith Please read the note at the bottom of my answer.
